# Building a query string for Bing Maps directions that uses My Location as a starting point

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, query-string

**Background:**

We are building a web app using Ember/Javascript that uses Mapbox for our application map. Because China has Google blocked, when we link a user out to 'get directions', we send them to Bing Maps instead using a query string. However, after carefully combing through the documentation (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx), I have found that we are unable to send a user to a page that shows directions from their location to an address.

**The Question:**

Can I build a query param string for Bing Maps similar to the method used to build one for Google Maps?

**Code:**

In Google Maps, the query string would look like this:

```
var query = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current Location/' + address;
```

In Bing Maps, I would like to build a similar query:

```
var query = 'http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?rtp=pos.MyLocation~adr.' + address;
```

In the documentation for Bing Maps I could find no way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it is not possible to do what you want to do with Bing Maps custom url.

Here is what's inside the documentation about the route parameter:

> Defines the start and end of a route to draw on the map, each separated by a tilde (~). Each of the waypoints is defined by either a pos (position) or adr (address) identifier. These identifiers are described in the table below.
>
> A complete route contains at least two waypoints. For example, a route
>   with two waypoints is defined by the following: rtp="A"~"B"
>
> You can also specify an incomplete route. For example, you can define
>   only the start of a route: rtp="A"~
>
> Or, you can enter only the end of a route: rtp=~"B"
>
> If you provide only one waypoint, the driving directions panel is
>   displayed with the provided waypoint, but no route is drawn.

So you can set the destination point to be your choice and the interface will be initialized with this as destination and let the user enter its own adresse or use its current position to generate the route.

Here is the example :

http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?rtp=~pos.50.626177_2.765149_Nico%27s%20House

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Bing Maps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/create-a-custom-map-url#driving-directions-parameters) that can be done by adding the `rtp` parameter to the url and having each waypoint seperated by a "~".

`https://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?rtp=adr.Seattle,WA~adr.One%20Microsoft%20Way,Redmond,WA`

Comment: That does not answer the question. He's specifically asking for "my location". Like in a similar way you can tell google maps to go from "current+location" to an address, but bing does nothing with this query.